# Newsletter sign up box covers up unknown location warning while editing profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, profile-page

When editing my profile, I noticed the newsletter signup box covers up the warning that my location isn't recognized. Shouldn't the warning be a little more important than the newsletter sign up I see every time I go to edit my profile?

[image: Editor error]

Firefox 10.0.2 on Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location helper text has been moved to below the input, rather than beside it, so it no longer collides with the newsletter signup box. Thanks for the report.